# Can I use a higher ohm resistance relay?

Tags: relay, resistance

I'd like to build the circuit detailed [here](http://www.simprojects.nl/toggle_to_momentary.htm), which calls for a 12V DC 260Ω resistance relay:

[image]

Looking at [some relays](http://uk.rs-online.com/web/c/relays/general-purpose-relays/non-latching-relays/#esid=cl_4294967294,cl_4294959386,cl_4294959493,cl_4294959494,cl_4294957569,cl_4294956147,cl_27&sort-by=P_breakPrice1&sort-order=asc&applied-dimensions=4294886074), what consequence would using [a 400Ω relay](http://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/non-latching-relays/0492907/) have? Would I be able to use one without a problem?

Unrelated: I believe it's a non-latching SPST NO relay that I need here, right? From what I understand, a SPDT can function as a SPST by ignoring one of the pins; is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 400 ohm relay will stay closed longer. You should reduce the capacitor by about 260/400, so about 220uF in order to make the time similar.

Yes, you can just ignore the normally closed contact.

Answer (score 1):

A higher ohm relay would have the consequence of slowing down the charge of the capacitor. So just pick a smaller capacitor to go with it. The author notes something like that from this quote: " You can also use a 5V relay and supply, but you may need to experiment with the capacitor value. (100uF ….470uF). "
Your other question is completely correct. Just ignore the throw you don't want to use.